# unwanted new line on Output using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML structure:

```
    <method constructor="true" name="Main" public="true">
    <parameterList/>
    <block>
        <call>
            <callAttrbute>
                <variable name="addEventListener"/>
            </callAttrbute>
            <fieldAccess target="Event" name="ENTER_FRAME"/>
            <variable name="onEnterFrame"/>
        </call>
            <block>
    </method>
```

The XML represents the structure of the follow code:

```
        public function Main(){
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame);
        }
```

My template looks something like:

```
 <xsl:template match="method">
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="@public">public </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>private </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="@static"><xsl:text>static </xsl:text></xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
 </xsl:template>
```

I want the following output (the same,just for example):

```
public function Main(){
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame);
        }
```

But the translate result is:

```
public Main()
        {
addEventListener
(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame);
}
```

In the result there are so many unwanted newlines and spaces, and it seems that the new line comes from the stylesheet.
How can I get the right format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know to prevent unwanted newlines is concatenating stuff in xslt itself like the below. This gives the required result in XML Spy 2011, but may not give the same in (for example) Saxon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="method">
        <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="@public">public </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>private </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose><xsl:if test="@static"><xsl:text>static </xsl:text></xsl:if><xsl:text>function </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@name"/>{
        <xsl:call-template name="callAttribute"/>}
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="callAttribute">
        <xsl:value-of select="block/call/callAttribute/variable/@name"/>(<xsl:value-of select="block/call/fieldAccess/@target"/>.<xsl:value-of select="block/call/fieldAccess/@name"/>, <xsl:value-of select="block/call/variable/@name"/>)
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the given input, this leads to (in XML Spy):

```
public function Main{
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame)
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps it woks，but not a good way, my xsl stylesheet and source document is a little complex. Also ths.

Answer (score 1):

I fix this problem in a simple but not a good way.

Every plain text that will output to target file should be wrapped with `<xsl:text></xsl:text>`,include new line character and space character.

```
<xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>method</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
```

In order to control the format of target file,i insert some new line character and space character according the depth of the node.

First define a template.

```
<xsl:template name="show_lead_space_depth">
   <xsl:param name="nodedepth"/>
      <xsl:if test="$nodedepth=1 ">
   <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="$nodedepth=2">
   <xsl:text>&#x9;&#x9;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Then call it when need.

```
   <xsl:call-template name="show_lead_space_depth">
        <xsl:with-param name="nodedepth" select="count(ancestor::*)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(@name)" />
```

Also you can use this before template blocks .. :

```
<xsl:strip-space select="element_name"/>
```

But normalize-space() function should work and that is more preferred.

Comment: Seems that your strategy is useful for whitespace that comes from between or within nodes in the source document, but My Problem is the space or the newline from the xsl style file.